# ASP.NET membership provider generates two applications in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using the below defined membership provider web config settings. when I access my admin pages to start to add roles and users to the system generated SQL Server tables I see two applications created. one with a application name of "/" and the second is called what my setting is configured to `PolyWebSite`.

My steps are:

1. as an unauthenticated user I browse to role config page to add admin and other roles. this is when the first application is created.
2. I browse to a custom user page where I add users and assign them roles. also as an unauthenticated user. this is when a second application is created with the name `PolyWebSite` as set in my `web.config`

   ```
   <roleManager enabled="true" />
   <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSql2005MembershipProvider">
       <providers>
           <add name="AspNetSql2005MembershipProvider" 
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0" 
                connectionStringName="SqlConnString" 
                enablePasswordReset="true" 
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
                applicationName="PolyWebSite" 
                requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
                minRequiredPasswordLength="1" 
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
                passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
                passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
                passwordFormat="Clear"/>
       </providers>
   </membership>
   ```

Comment: figured it out: added details to the roleManager part of the web.config to be in sync with membership section. items added were connectionStringName and applicationName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out: added details to the roleManager part of the web.config to be in sync with membership section. items added were connectionStringName and applicationName.

```
   <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSql2005MembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSql2005MembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
             connectionStringName="SqlConnString" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
             applicationName="PolyWebSite" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="1" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
             passwordFormat="Clear"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>


    <roleManager enabled ="true" defaultProvider ="SqlRoleProvider" >
      <providers>
        <add name ="SqlRoleProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
          connectionStringName="SqlConnString"
          applicationName="PolyWebSite"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```